# Generics competence problem: Map<K, V> inside class / method without K and V in their signature

Tags: java, generics, collections

Please, consult me with my probably stupid question.

I prepared a little bit of an abstract explanation for my problem.
Please, do not try to repeat it on your computer, this is just for showing the logic.

My class is the following (again, this is just for illustration):

```
public class Operation<D1, D2, R> extends AbstractOperation<D1, D2> implements InterfaceOperation<D1, D2, R> {

    @Override
    public Collection<R> doOperation(Collection<D1> collection_1, Collection<D2> collection_2) {    

        Map<String, String> map_1 = createMap_1(collection_1);
        Map<String, String> map_2 = createMap_2(collection_2);

        return (Collection<R>) ... ;
    }
}
```

I have a *class Operation<D1, D2, R>* which implements contract *InterfaceOperation<D1, D2, R>*. Inside abstract class just some common methods. So, the signature for *Operation<D1, D2, R>*, for *InterfaceOperation<D1, D2, R>* and for *doOperation(Collection collection_1, Collection collection_2)* cannot be changed.

*D1* and *D2* is a type of elements inside Collection, which enters to the *doOperation* method.

So, *Collection* consists of the *Data<K, V>* elements, which I am going to map to the *map_1* and *map_2*.

The *Data<K, V>* can have any combinations of Objects, it is generic and it works well, but, the *Map<String, String> map_1* (and the second one) restricts me to use in *Data<K, V>* only *<String, String>*.

I need to have these maps (*map_1* and *map_2*) be generic, like *Map<K, V> map_1* (the same for *map_2*), but without placing *<K, V>* into the method or class signature:

```
public class Operation<D1, D2, R> extends AbstractOperation<D1, D2> implements InterfaceOperation<D1, D2, R> {

    @Override
    public Collection<R> doOperation(Collection<D1> collection_1, Collection<D2> collection_2) {


        Map<K, V> map_1 = createMap_1(collection_1);
        Map<K, V> map_2 = createMap_2(collection_2);

        return (Collection<R>) ... ;
    }
}
```

How it is possible? If this is a concrete topic in Generics, please, let me know, I will read it.
Or it is impossible without changing the class/interface/method signature?

Thank you!

**Update #1:**
The methods *createMap_1* and *createMap_2* are inside *abstract class AbstractOperation<D1, D2>* and looks like the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractOperation<D1, D2> {

    protected Map<Integer, String> createMap_1(Collection<D1> collection_1) {
        return collection_1.stream()
                .map(e -> (Data<Integer, String>) e)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Data::getKey, DataRow::getValue));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: So, what's the signature for method `createMap_1` and `createMap_2`?

Comment: Dear Ale, I have updated my question with a whole method body. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like these should be in a subclass of `Operation` that assign specific types to `D1`, `D2`, and `R`, e.g. `class StringOperation extends Operation<String, String, String> { ... }`.

Comment: Dear Louis, D1, D2 and R are Collection type. From these collections I extract the objects Data<K,V> and put them into Map, but map is not generic, but have to be generic. Or I have to take maps out and operate with only collections... I should have a possibility to put to Data any kind of objects, but because of Map they can be only the types, I wrote inside Maps.

Comment: The point of generics is that you should never need to cast pretty much anything.  Making concrete subclasses where you make the actual types explicit is the intended solution.  If `K` and `V` can only be `Integer` and `String`, because that's the actual implementation of `createMap_1`, then the generics should reflect that.

Comment: Dear Louis, K and V can be any kind of object: Integer - String, String - Integer, String - AnotherOneObject.... The Map now restricts the possible types.

Comment: I got an idea - what if I use a local inner class inside doOperation method?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `doOperation` method doesn't care about the types of the keys and values of these maps, you can use [wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html):

```
Map<?, ?> map_1 = createMap_1(collection_1);
Map<?, ?> map_2 = createMap_2(collection_2);
```

Note that this limits the types of operations you can safely perform on the maps. For example, you won't be able to put values into the map or get values from the map without unsafe casts, since this method won't know the type of keys to use.

Comment: Dear Tim, your solution is working, thank you! It is strange, that I don`t come up with this... Ale Zalazar and Louis Wasserman (and others, who tried) thank you too!